# Prime number triplet problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

In a series of prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13... some 3 consecutive numbers from that series $p$, $q$, $r$ exist such that $p^2+q^2+r^2$ is also a prime number. How many such triplets $(p,q,r)$ exist?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each of the given prime is $\ne 3$ then $p^2\equiv q^2\equiv r^2\equiv 1 \pmod3$ so $p^2+q^2+r^2=3$ which is impossible, so one of them is 3.

So the only posibile candidate are $2,3,5$ or $3,5,7$.

Comment: Two odds and an even also ...